# How can a bundle provide new column type to Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to provide custom (doctrine orm) column type in a bundle, but I don't know how to register them:

```php
Type::addType('my_col', 'MyColType');
$em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()
   ->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('my_col', 'my_col');
```

MyBundleClass::boot() looks like a good place, but inside boot(), I can not access container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the property `container` of the Bundle class to retrieve the right entity manager (usually `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager`)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class AcmeMyBundle extends Bundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        /* @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

        $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping(...);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `PrependExtensionInterface` https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/prepend_extension.html:

```
class FooBundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface {

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('doctrine', [
            'dbal' => [
                'types' => [
                    'foo' => FooType::class,
                ],
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```